# Mount Solaris Partition in Linux

Tags: filesystems, mount, solaris

I have a USB disk which when connected to a CentOS 6.5 system shows this as the output in fdisk -l.

```
Disk /dev/sdn: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00113504

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdn1   *           5      243200  1953471870   bf  Solaris
```

I want to mount this file system on the system and so far it has been a nightmare. This is what I have tried.
1. Installed UFS support using elrepo. Tried all the options that ufs provides (various ufstypes).
2. Installed ZFS support. Did not really understand if I could do anything further with it.

Some of the mount commands that I tried are below. I am not listing all of them as the permutations are far too many.

```
mount -t ufs -oro,ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdn1 /mnt
mount -t ufs -oro,ufstype=sunx86 /dev/sdn1 /mnt
mount -t ufs -oro,ufstype=sun /dev/sdn1 /mnt
mount -t ufs -oro,ufstype=old /dev/sdn1 /mnt
```

All these commands report the UFS kernel module reporting as bad magic number in dmesg.

Can anyone help? How could I mount the filesystem in Linux. Read-Only mount would be good enough.

Replies to comments:

1. `dmesg | grep -i solaris` does not show anything. However, both `parted` and `fdisk` show only one partition which is sdn1.
2. `zpool status` and `zpool list` both show "no pools available".

Comment: Paste the various `mount` commands you used and their outputs will be useful.

Comment: You may need to use a partition other than sdn1. What partitions are shown if you run `dmesg | grep -i solaris ` ?

Comment: What do you get from `zpool list` or `zpool status`?

Comment: edited the question to information about what was asked in comments above.

Comment: What happens if you just run `mount /dev/sdn1 /mnt` ?

Comment: if I run     mount /dev/sdn1 /mnt     it tells me that the filesystem must be specified.

Comment: Just because the partition type is Solaris does not in and of itself mean the file system type is UDF. Are you certain that it is UDF? You can test with utilities like [disktype](http://disktype.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @bdowning - I agree, partition of type solaris doesn't imply ufs. But then how do I find what type of partition is it? Utilities like disktype, fstyp etc. do not return anything meaningful. It is an unknown partition type for them.

Comment: Seems likely that is has no file system then. That's why I asked "are you certain that it is UDF?", if so, how are you certain?

Comment: @bdowning When the disk was mounted on Solaris, it showed "ufs" and worked fine. I am assuming that every time you say UDF, you actually mean ufs.

Comment: Sorry, simple typo

Comment: Was the disk previously connected on a SPARC or x86 Solaris computer?

Comment: It seems like the disk was connected on an x86 Solaris and shows UFS there.

Answer (score 3):

As you stated in your last comment, if I understand it correctly, that the partition mounts fine on both SPARC and x86 running Solaris 11, you can be sure this is not `UFS`. Big endian `UFS` used on SPARC hardware doesn't mount on x86 hardware and reciprocally.

That leaves `hsfs`, `pcfs` and `ZFS` as potential contenders, and perhaps `udf` too.

The simpler way would be to check on Solaris what is the file system type with either the `mount` or `fstyp` commands.

Linux should be able to mount `hsfs` (`isofs`), `pcfs` (`vfat`) and `udf`.

If ZFS, only `zpool` version 28/`zfs` version 5 or older can be imported/mounted on the Linux side (and possibly only zpool 23/zfs 4 if ZFS fuse).

---

**Edit**:

After you stated the file system is UFS on x86, the file system to use should ufs  with ufstype=sunx86 or ufstype=sun. However, you are not using the right device.

/dev/sdn1 is the primary partition used by Solaris but this partitions is normally subdivided in underlying partitions, named slices in Solaris terminology. This is similar to logical partitions.

You should then identify what names were given to the slices by the Linux kernel by running `dmesg | grep solaris` and mount the right one (example if slice 5 is reported) :

```
mount -t ufs -oro,ufstype=sunx86 /dev/sdn5 /mnt
```

Note that not all slices contains file systems, they might be used as raw devices like the swap.

Comment: My mistake. It works fine on Solaris x86. I am not sure about SPARC. Edited the earlier comment to reflect it. And it is indeed UFS as visible in x86 Solaris.